# How to migrate/upgrade your acronyms from acro v2 to acro v3? (2019 to 2020)

Tags: acronyms, acro

[The acro package has recently been upgraded](https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/blob/master/HISTORY) to v3 ([doc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cgnieder/acro/master/doc/acro-manual.pdf)) – e.g. TexLive 2019 still includes [acro v2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cgnieder/acro/v2.10/acro_en.pdf), TexLive 2020 includes acro v3, which is a complete rewrite with many new features.
The question I'd now have is whether there is some kind of migration script, that allows you to migrate at least the `\DeclareAcronym` listing, so you don't have to go through a lot of them hand by hand.

Does not have to be included in acro itself or does not have to be a LaTeX solution – a simple shell or Python script could probably also help – or even a web interface/service, as you only need to run that once.

Some examples on how they differ:

- `foreign-lang` is now `foreign-babel` e.g.

---

Cross-posted [in the acro issue tracker](https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/issues/167).

Comment: a call to `sed` usually does the job, but it would be easier to give some suggestion with a MWE showing the way accro v3 and v2 differs.

Comment: Well… it's all in the docs and it really always depends on what features you use of v2. [Here is the last v2 doc](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cgnieder/acro/v2.10/acro_en.pdf) and here [is v3](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cgnieder/acro/master/doc/acro-manual.pdf). Anyway, I'll add some examples.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly not the best answer in the long-term, but I've noticed acro v3 [does have an option to continue using the v2 syntax](https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/releases/tag/v3.0beta) even when you load v3.

Just load the package as this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[version=2]{acro}
```

Of course, this is no real solution and only a time-limited workaround, I guess, but I have not heard of deprecation plans. The doc of [version 3.2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cgnieder/acro/v3.2/doc/acro-manual.pdf) page 4 (section 4.1) still lists that as an option, you can use and makes no note of whether and when this may be removed. ([@cgnieder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/cgnieder) may be more likely to know the details here. :) )

Comment: It's not using the syntax of v2, it's loading the last v2 release wholesale (https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/issues/156).  When running v3 a lot of changed keys should log their new equivalents, e.g. [this line means the log would redirect you from `foreign-lang` to `foreign-babel`](https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/blob/9a56e414b0eb82ff89241decc66da9620f2292df/code/acro.upgrade.code.tex#L171).